# SQL Query filtering advice

Tags: mysql, sql, doctrine

I'm not sure what I'm trying to do is possible but I've been trying to get different methods to a solution I need but so far I've come up empty handed.

Lets say I have 2 tables (just an example, in my case theres a hell of a lot more + alot more data)

One called clients and the other called form_data.
We have multiple clients in the clients table and in the form_data table we have multiple rows for each company present in the clients table.  In form_data we store the serialized data from different forms. (id and data)

I'm currently pulling all records from the form_data table and I am trying to use a regexp on the data column to filter for instance that the value 'motor oil' is found in them.

I would like a way to do this filter but filter the company and not the forms .. so I want to find the forms that have 'motor oil' in them and the remove all entries for COMPANIES that don't have this match, but I want to keep all the forms showing for the companies that match.

I can post my query but it is rather long and i think if we can solve the above it should be sufficient for me to implement into the actual query.

Regards

EDIT:

```
SELECT f.form_question_has_answer_id AS f__form_question_has_answer_id, f.form_question_has_answer_request AS f__form_question_has_answer_request, 
f.form_question_has_answer_form_id AS f__form_question_has_answer_form_id, f.form_question_has_answer_user_id AS f__form_question_has_answer_user_id, 
p.project_company_has_user_id AS p__project_company_has_user_id, p.project_company_has_user_project_id AS p__project_company_has_user_project_id, 
p.project_company_has_user_user_id AS p__project_company_has_user_user_id, c.company_id AS c__company_id, c.company_hall_no AS c__company_hall_no, 
c.company_type AS c__company_type, c.company_company_name AS c__company_company_name, c.company_country AS c__company_country, 
c.company_stand_number AS c__company_stand_number, c.company_image_file_1 AS c__company_image_file_1, p2.project_id AS p2__project_id, 
p2.project_name AS p2__project_name, u.user_id AS u__user_id, u.user_username AS u__user_username, f2.form_id AS f2__form_id 
FROM form_question_has_answer f 
INNER JOIN project_company_has_user p ON f.form_question_has_answer_user_id = p.project_company_has_user_user_id 
INNER JOIN company c ON p.project_company_has_user_company_id = c.company_id 
INNER JOIN project p2 ON p.project_company_has_user_project_id = p2.project_id 
INNER JOIN user u ON p.project_company_has_user_user_id = u.user_id 
INNER JOIN form f2 ON p.project_company_has_user_project_id = f2.form_project_id 
WHERE f.form_question_has_answer_id IN ('19262', '21560', '23088', '22660', '14772', '18495', '18720', '21625', '19957', '20943') 
AND ((f2.form_template_name = "custom" AND p.project_company_has_user_garbage_collection = 0 AND p.project_company_has_user_project_id = 29) AND f.form_question_has_answer_request REGEXP 'item-cadcae') 
ORDER BY company_company_name asc
```

The query is from a doctrine query.

EDIT:
If i have a company with 10 forms in the form_data table if i filter by 'motor oil' all forms for that company that don't have motor oil are removed.. so if only 1 of the 10 forms for company id 144 has the word motor oil then the other 9 forms are lost in the query.. I want to keep them. What I want is any company that didn't find any forms with that match (motor oil) to have all their forms removed from the search.

Comment: Please don't hesitate to post your query. If it's long, people just won't read it (which is better than not having it at all)

Comment: Also show sample data of your tables to know the type(text,xml,int,..etc) of data we deal with

Comment: Better yet, put the schema and query up at [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/).

Comment: Also say if you have a company with 'motor oil' in 1 rown and not in other rows are you going to show 1 row or ignore the company completely?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All form data for all customers who have at least one form that matches the search:

```
SELECT * FROM `form_data`
WHERE `clientid` IN (
  SELECT DISTINCT `clientid` FROM `form_data`
  WHERE `data` RLIKE '[[:<:]]motor oil[[:>:]]'
);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT
    c.*
FROM 
    clients as c
    INNER JOIN (
        select 
            *
        from 
            forms
        where 
            sometext like '%motor oil%'
        ) as f
        ON f.client = c.id
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/5b616/1

in this part:

```
select 
    *
from 
      forms
where 
      sometext like '%motor oil%'
```

you can put any query that selects the relevant rows from your forms table with the appropriate filters.

you can do the inverse too with a left outer join where null technique.. though in this case modifying the subquery to return a list of distinct clients will probably give you more like the results you expect:

```
SELECT
    c.*
FROM 
    clients as c
    LEFT OUTER JOIN (
        select 
            distinct 
                client
        from 
            forms
        where 
            sometext like '%motor oil%'
        ) as f
        ON f.client = c.id
where f.client is null
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/5b616/4

so with your query something like:

```
SELECT
    c.*
FROM 
    company AS c 
    INNER JOIN (
                SELECT 
                    DISTINCT c.company_id 
                FROM 
                    form_question_has_answer f 
                    INNER JOIN project_company_has_user p 
                        ON f.form_question_has_answer_user_id = p.project_company_has_user_user_id 
                    INNER JOIN company c 
                        ON p.project_company_has_user_company_id = c.company_id 
                    INNER JOIN project p2 
                        ON p.project_company_has_user_project_id = p2.project_id 
                    INNER JOIN user u 
                        ON p.project_company_has_user_user_id = u.user_id 
                    INNER JOIN form f2 
                        ON p.project_company_has_user_project_id = f2.form_project_id 
                WHERE 
                    f.form_question_has_answer_id IN ('19262', '21560', '23088', '22660', '14772', '18495', '18720', '21625', '19957', '20943') 
                    AND ((f2.form_template_name = "custom" 
                    AND p.project_company_has_user_garbage_collection = 0 
                    AND p.project_company_has_user_project_id = 29) 
                    AND f.form_question_has_answer_request REGEXP 'item-cadcae') 
                ORDER BY company_company_name asc
            ) as f
                ON f.company_id= c.id
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure What do you mean by  keeping all the forms showing for the companies that match?
Aren't just getting at this...

```
select * from clients inner join form_data on clients.id = form_data.id where form_data.[data] like '%motor  oil%'
```

Answer (score 0):

This will return all forms with 'motor oil' in them filled for the companies which also have 'motor oil' in their name:

```
SELECT  *
FROM    clients c
JOIN    form_data fd
ON      fd.client = c.id
WHERE   fd.data RLIKE '[[:<:]]motor oil[[:>:]]'
        AND c.name RLIKE '[[:<:]]motor oil[[:>:]]'
```